# Q: how to unnest bags from complicated data structure in PIG

Tags: hadoop, nested, apache-pig, bag

Originally I have structure like this:

```
+-------+-------+----+----+----+-----+
| time  | type  | s1 | s2 | id | p1  |
+-------+-------+----+----+----+-----+
| 10:30 | send  | a  | b  |  1 | 110 |
| 10:35 | send  | c  | d  |  1 | 120 |
| 10:31 | reply | e  | f  |  3 | 221 |
| 10:33 | reply | a  | c  |  1 | 210 |
| 10:34 | send  | a  | a  |  3 | 113 |
| 10:32 | reply | c  | d  |  3 | 157 |
+-------+-------+----+----+----+-----+
```

I want to normalize the table:

1. group the entries by id,
2. inside each group, find out the oldest send type entry,
3. replace s1, s2 of other entries with the values from that oldest send type entry

```

```
+-------+-------+----+----+----+-----+
| time  | type  | s1 | s2 | id | p1  |
+-------+-------+----+----+----+-----+
| 10:30 | send  | a  | b  |  1 | 110 |
| 10:35 | send  | a  | b  |  1 | 120 |
| 10:33 | reply | a  | b  |  1 | 210 |
| 10:31 | reply | a  | a  |  3 | 221 |
| 10:34 | send  | a  | a  |  3 | 113 |
| 10:32 | reply | a  | a  |  3 | 157 |
+-------+-------+----+----+----+-----+
```

this is how I tried to tackle the problem:

```
events_groupby_id = GROUP events BY id;
events_normalized = FOREACH events_groupby_id {
   f_reqs = FILTER events BY type matches 'send';
   o_reqs = ORDER events BY time ASC;
   req = LIMIT o_reqs 1;
   GENERATE req, events;
};
```

I am stuck at here. Because I found that events_normalized became a complicated structure with nested bags and I don't know how to flatten correctly.

events_normalized | req:bag{:tuple()} | events:bag{:tuple()}

From here, what should I do to achieve the data structure that I want? I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest the bags in `events_normalized` using `FLATTEN`:

```
events_flattened = FOREACH events_normalized GENERATE 
    FLATTEN(req), 
    FLATTEN(events);
```

This creates a crossproduct between `req` and `events`, but since there is only one tuple in `req`, you end up with only one record for each of your original entries. The schema for `events_flattened` is:

```
req::time | req::type | req::s1 | req::s2 | req::id | req::p1 | events::time | events::type | events::s1 | events::s2 | events::id | events::p1
```

So now you can refer to the fields you wish to keep, using `events` for the original entries and `req` for the replacements from the oldest send type entry:

```
final = FOREACH events_flattened GENERATE 
    events::time AS time, 
    events::type AS type, 
    req::s1 AS s1, 
    req::s2 AS s2, 
    events::id AS id, 
    events::p1 AS p1;
```